# removing the one pixel clearance when using CSS text-decoration: underline

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, styling, text-decorations

I have the following CSS and markup on my site which produces an underline when I hover over the `Account` link.

By default, the underline is shown one pixel clear of the text. Is it possible to have the underline *directly* under the text *without* the one pixel clearance.

I would like this for all links on my site, if possible.

```
a:active {
    outline: none;
}

a.current {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #000000;
    outline: none;
}
a:hover, a.active {
    color: #000000;
    outline: medium none;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

<a href="http://www.ayrshireminis.com/account/login/">Account</a>
```

Comment: You could replicate it with `border-bottom` and 0 `padding-bottom`.

Comment: @ajm Do you have an example? 0 for border-bottom and padding-bottom?

Comment: Christoph's answer below should to the trick.

Comment: @ajm Have a look at the jsFiddle example. I'm not sure if it does.

Comment: Did you read my comment? Did it work out for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a bottom border, but you need to enable inline-block styling in order to adjust the line-height of the anchor properly:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #c64;

    /* cross-browser inline-block styling */
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;

    /* alter line-height until the border appears where you want it */
    line-height: .7em;
}

a:hover, a:active{
    padding-bottom:0;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
```

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5d7j3/2/)

Comment: moz-inline-stack really isn't necessary anymore (FF2!) and I prefer putting the IE-declarations into a IE-stylesheet if you really want to support those old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't modify that. However you could fake it with something like the following:

```
a:hover, a.active{
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}​

a{
    padding-bottom:0;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:.8 /*adjust accordingly*/;
}
```

the `display:inline-block;` is needed for the line-height to work properly.

Comment: Hmmm...it doesn't seem to have any affect with regards to bringing the border/line closer to the text. Can you see this working in jsFiddle for example?

Comment: Here this code on jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/y49jN/ - I can't seem to get it to work. Can you?

Comment: Sure, http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/y49jN/1/ - you need to add a displaytype for inline-elements.

Comment: @crmpicco You need to be aware of the font-size though, it may differ between browsers/OS. The finetuning might get a bit tedious.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to make the `<a>` a block, otherwise padding can't effect anything.

`a { display: block; line-height:0.75em; ... etc }`

`a:hover { border-bottom:1px solid #000; }`

http://jsfiddle.net/y49jN/3/

Comment: This would not work if he wants anchors to display within lines of text.

Comment: @Christoph inline elements have never been able to have padding or margin or width or height specified.  At least to my knowledge.

Comment: @Kirean well, I'm sorry, but you are both wrong. Of course inline-elements are affected by/can have padding as you can see in mcp's fiddle. It's just that it's not accounted to the extrinsic element dimensions because inline-elements have no own block-context. Width can't be declared, that's true. This article might help you understand: http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/

Comment: @Christoph good article.  I don't usually have a use for declaring only left/right padding, so I had overgeneralized that since top/bottom padding didnt get applied, none of it did.  Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

I have also found that setting the `height` of the div, span or p to less than the `font-size` and using `border-bottom: 1px solid black` instead of `text-decoration: underline` brings the border closer to the text or element.